# ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'invalid sender'}

Tags: web3.py

I'm trying to transfer some test ether from one Metamask address to another 
using the private key that I exported from it. But it always return a error code of -32000 with a message of 'Invalid sender'.

```
import web3 
import json
from eth_account import Account
from web3 import Web3
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/apiKey'))
acct = Account.privateKeyToAccount('Private key from Metamask')
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(acct.address)
transaction = {'
to' : toAccount,
'value': 1000000000,
'gas': 2000000,
'gasPrice': 234567897654321,
'nonce': nonce,
'chainId': 1
}
key = acct.privateKey
signed = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(transaction, key)
w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, error `-32000` means that the transaction signature is wrong.

The issue is **chainId**, because **chainId** is important during the transaction signing. Basically, your Python code signs the transaction with `chainId: 1`, but the infura ropsten node does not recognize the signature, because it expects `chainId: 3`.

`1` is `mainnet`'s chain id.

For `ropsten` you should use chain id `3`. You can find list of network ids [here.](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md)

P. S.

It's unrelated, but you only need `21000` gas to do a simple `ether` transfer and you probably should get your [`gasPrice` from `web3`.](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_gasprice)

Comment: P. P. S.
I slightly modified your [code](https://gist.github.com/ivandru/e6d08f503caf8c59e77857e870e65450) and got a successful [transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x18ba6c7ac2cb1c0b37c904aba94f4d59fb3c2fd0b2fe269f294622101e86611d) after running it.